# Setting a converter on a GroupDescriptor in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, converters

I have a read-only datagrid bound to a domain data source. The data that I'm binding to has an ID property that I'm resolving on the grid through a converter (a simple int -> string mapping). The domain data source also has a GroupDescriptor on it, and this works, except I'm grouping by that column which has a converter on it.

Unfortunately the group header doesn't use the Converter and therefore just displays the ID, which is not desirable. I can replace the control template for the group header and explicitly use a converter on the template, but this is obviously not an ideal solution as I'm hard-coding the template to the converter.

Is there a way to use a converter on a group descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that if you create a `PropertyGroupDescription` in code, it allows you to supply an `IValueConverter` in the constructor, so this would appear to be an answer.